# How do I make a button click play music and the same button click restart the music

Tags: java, android

I want to create a button in which a click causes the Media player to start and play music, and another click on the same button (While the music is playing) to restart the music. I am a complete beginner in java and android, so please explain each step.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at this section first - [help/on-topic] , as this question asks for a "how-to" instead of problem solving. What have you tried so far ? What problems have you encountered ? As for your question you can start by having a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: We're not here to write code from scratch for you. Most of this information would be easily found in a search. Here's one to get you started with a button that plays music: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678873/android-button-click-to-play-music-click-again-to-stop-music

Comment: Use `mp2.start();` in both the playing and not playing cases in the above example @CalvinP. provided.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse this can be done, you have to maintain states for your clicks.

So add conditions , 
  On Click -: 
      if(mediaPlayer Not Running)--> Start Media Player
      if(mediaPlayer Running)--> Restart The media Player.
  So you have to play with these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

use below code for puase and start music on same button click:

```
 btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();  //mp.stop();  for stop music
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }else{
                // Resume song
                if(mp!=null){
                 mp.setDataSource("/sdcard/Music/maine.mp3");//Write your location here  
                 mp.prepare();  
                 mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Am I wrong, or the first `null` check is placed in the wrong order ? `if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){`